# Como escrever string XML em uma tag utilizando XMLSerialize

Tags: c#, xml

Quando passo a string e gero pelo XmlWriterSettings.xmlSerialize passando os dados sem caracteres epeciais, ele ainda gera da forma seguinte. Resumidamente, tenho um documento xml dentro de uma tag.

```
<Valor>&amp;lt;![CDATA[&amp;lt;CFe xmlns:xsi=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&amp;quot; xmlns:xsd=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
```